Importing fbx animated character, mesh deformed
I'm trying to import animated character from motion builder to blender. I still get though deformation like this. How can I approach fixing it?


Seems to me you have to weight paint some bones to the appropriate part. Have you tried disconnecting the armature from the model and see if it snaps into place? Or unassigning all vertices from the bones in the vertex groups tab.
